# Conversion of SDP relaxation of Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP) to standard SDP form

Tags: convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, hamiltonian-path, semidefinite-programming, relaxations

The standard SDP formulation is given as :
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{X\in H^{n}}  \quad& \langle X,M_{0} \rangle\\
\textrm{s.t.}  \quad& l_{s} \leq \langle X, M_{s} \rangle \leq u_{s}, \quad & s=1,...,p,\\
\quad & X \succcurlyeq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $M_{0}, M_{1}, ..., M_{p} \in \mathbb{H}^{n} $ and

\begin{align*}
        (l_{s}, u_{s}) \in (\{-\infty\} \cup \mathbb{R} ) \times (\mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\})
\end{align*}

for every $s=1,...,p$
Here, $\langle \rangle$ indicates the frobenius inner product.

The SDP relaxation of the TSP problem can be written (as per [this paper](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/zr/18/n018p005.pdf)) as :
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{X}  \quad& -\frac{1}{2}\langle D,X \rangle + \frac{\alpha}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}d_{ij}\\
\textrm{s.t.}  \quad& \langle A_{i},X \rangle = 2 + \alpha - \beta \quad & i=1,...,n\\
\quad& \langle B_{i}, X\rangle = 2(n\alpha - \beta) \quad & i=1,...,n \\
\quad & 2(\alpha - 1) \leq \langle C_{ij},X \rangle \leq 2\alpha \quad & i,j = 1,...,n\\
\quad & X \succcurlyeq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Where $D$ is the Distance Matrix of the graph,
$A_{i} \in S_{n}$ and $a_{ii} = 1$ with all other entries $0$,
$B_{i} \in S_{n}$ and $b_{ii} = 2$ with all other entries in row $i$ and column $i$ are $1$ and all other entries is $0$
$C_{ij}$ has $1$ in the positions $c_{ij}$ and $c_{ji}$ with all other entries $0$ and
$n$ is the number of vertices in the graph

Is it possible to convert the SDP relaxation of the TSP problem into the standard SDP formulation?

Comment: It essentially is in that form, except for converting equalities into a pair of inequalities if you really insist. But the question is why? Already from your form it is clear this is an SDP. There are, by the way, many different "standard" formulations but the particular choice of one of them never really matters.

Comment: I'm trying to use an algorithm which is in the standard form I mentioned. That algorithm is in terms of the matrices Mm ls and us, so it's easier for me to directly apply it if its in that form

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek can you convert the problem if possible?

Comment: For every constraint of the form $\langle K, X\rangle=b$ you write $b\leq \langle K,X\rangle\leq b$, otherwise everything you have is already in the right form. Maybe you just skip the constant term in the objective. What is the software called you are feeding this into?

Comment: It's not software, I'm writing my own code based on this paper : https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7403152. I understood the rest, thanks.